# manipulation of processor speed without changing the processor

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor

is it possible to replace a ram with higher storage on a machine with a processor of low speed? is speed of processing increased or decreased.

i want to replace the ram drive of my machine with a higher storage ram so that I can try to manipulate the processor speed without changing the processors, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use faster RAM, currently up to DDR4-4800MHz. Using higher capacity RAM would also be useful if running out of RAM capacity is what’s slowing you down. Using a high-speed solid-state drive (SSD) would also speed up task that require reading or writing from storage, including booting up the computer and running programs that use a lot of assets on the computer. You can also overclock both your CPU and RAM to make them faster, but this may void your warranty.

Additionally, you can use software. For example, you can use CCleaner to remove useless files which clutter your computer. You can also use it to disable unneeded scheduled tasks that your computer runs. If your computer has a spinning-disc hard drive, then you can try defragmenting it by using the built-in Windows defragger, or you can use the Defraggler program from the same people who make CCleaner. Of course, you can also try deleting programs or files you no longer need or use if it’s limited hard drive capacity that’s slowing you down.

If it’s web browsing that’s slow, you may want to consider using a faster browser, like Google Chrome or Firefox. You can also install browser extensions/add-ons like AdBlock and Ghostery to prevent unneeded things from being loaded on pages, making pages load faster.